# How can I store an array of custom objects in Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parse-platform

For my iOS application that uses Parse, I need to store an array of custom objects into a PFObject. I tried doing this, and I am getting the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (JSQMessage)'

Is there any possible way to store an array of custom objects in Parse? I can't seem to find a good answer for this.

For your reference, I am using the JSQMessages view controller library at https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

The array that I am trying to add to the PFObject is initialized with the code:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithText:initialtext sender:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] date:[NSDate date]],
                                     nil];
```

Comment: You can only add an array of other PFObjects or base types (Boolean, string..) . You cannot add an array of arbitrary objects

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any way to store the information in a PFObject, perhaps by converting it to some other valid data type?

Comment: Have you read the parse documentation on objects?

Comment: Yes, you can make a new PFObject type in your Parse.dashboard and create instances of that type for each of your `JSQMessage`s.  You can then add these PFObjects to an array column in your existing PFObject.  The Parse API automatically resolves the object references - See the relational data section - https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-pointers/iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom objects conform to the `NSCoding` protocol then yes, you can save them most definitely.

Here's an example for a Magic: The Gathering set

```
@interface MTGSet : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *code;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *releaseDate;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "MTGSet.h"

@implementation MTGSet

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:_name forKey:@"name"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_code forKey:@"code"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_releaseDate forKey:@"releaseDate"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    return [self initWithJSONDictionary:
            @{@"name" : [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"],
              @"code" : [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"code"],
              @"releaseDate" : [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"releaseDate"]}];
}

@end
```

Usage

```
MTGSet *set = [MTGSet new];
set.name = @"Magic 2015";
set.code = @"M15";
set.releaseDate = [NSDate date];

NSData *dataFromSet = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:set];
PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MyObject"];
object[@"set"] = dataFromSet;
[object save];

MTGSet *unarchivedSet = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:object[@"set"]];
NSLog(@"Here's the set: %@", unarchivedSet);
```

There are libraries out there to make this easier using the objective-c runtime which I recommend.

https://github.com/eladb/Parse-NSCoding